# show progress of recursive request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have recursive js script which send GET request and php script update xml data by 100 rows for once. But my problem is progress not displayed when I run script. I don't understand where is error or how can i fix it

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    function ProcessClear(start_position){

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            async:false, // set async false to wait for previous response; true for async
            url: "checkUrl.php?start=y&start_position="+start_position,
            dataType:"html",
            success: function(data){
                if( data == "done" ){
                    $('.at_test_red span').html( "end" );
                }else{
                    $('.at_test_red span').html( data );


                    ProcessClear( data );
                }
            }
        });

    }

    ProcessClear(1);
});
```

On this line `$('.at_test_red span').html( data );`  should be visible progess but it not working

Comment: Firstly never use `async: false`. You don't need it here as you're recursively calling the function in the callback of the previous request anyway. If you want to work out progress, all you need to do is keep a total of how many records you are going to download and how many you have downloaded, then get the % you are through.

Comment: well I am guessing the synchronous calls prevent the page from updating. Not sure why you are using synchronous

Comment: *On this line $('.at_test_red span').html( data ); should be visible progess but it not working* and what is `data`?

Comment: @Liam "data" contains next position for function start. In php script skip previous rows

Answer (score 1):

`async : false` causing this issue. Because script will run on single thread. It should be `true`.

> async:false, // set async false to wait for previous response; true for async

In order to achieve above intend, you should call `ProcessClear` function recursively when you get the response of previous request. i.e in `complete` or in `success` of ajax call.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    function ProcessClear(start_position){

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET", 
            async: true, //true is default         
            url: "checkUrl.php?start=y&start_position="+start_position,
            dataType:"html",
            success: function(data){
                if( data == "done" ){
                    $('.at_test_red span').html( "end" );
                }else{
                    $('.at_test_red span').html( data );


                    ProcessClear( data ); //<-- This will call only on getting response from previous request.
                }
            }
        });

    }

    ProcessClear(1);
});
```

Comment: sorry, but i get response in "data" and start function. Something wrong?

Comment: At first `ProcessClear(1);` will call only once on Doc Ready event. Whats wrong?